# VB.NET: Access window handles from a service

Tags: .net, windows, service

I am writing a .NET process monitoring application.
This application watches for suspicious processes running, and hides and suspends any of them. Then, it asks the user whether the process should be resumed or killed.

To hide/show windows, I use:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Function ShowWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> nCmdShow As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0
ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE)
```

I can't use a Windows Forms Application because:

- The application needs administrator privileges (to monitor admin processes), but non-admin users should be able to use it, and I don't want UAC prompts every time
- The application must be user-logon-insensitive: it must continue to run when a user logs off.

That's why I made a Windows Service, installed under the "LocalSystem" account. (User prompts are still handled by a Windows Forms Application that communicates with the background service.)

New problem: the service can not hide/show windows. If a window appears before the process is suspended, it is frozen but does not disappear, therefore the user sees it as "non-responding".

The function I used works from a Windows Forms Application. I found that in the service, MainWindowHandle always returns 0 for any process (stands for "invalid handle"), and the Win32 EnumThreadWindows function gets no handle at all. Even when passing the valid handle manually (retrieved from another app), the call has no effect.
Checking "Allow the service to interact with desktop" does not solve the problem.

Is there an alternative to solve this issue?

Sincerely,
E__Man.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by hiding a window?

Comment: Did you try using Application.setSuspendState?

Comment: @Krishnaraj R I think I can't use Application.setSuspendState from my service.

I use NtSuspendProcess to suspend a process, but this does not hide its windows.

Comment: @IInspectable My application could also be used to prevent other users from running a program: this program should not be able to display any information unless its owner gives the permission.

Comment: You won't get the sort of protection/prevention you seem to expect from managed code. You're going to have to go much, *much* deeper into the system to implement any sort of protection. That said, hiding a window makes it invisible to a human user. It distinctly doesn't make it invisible to a program, that can still find it, gather information, or toggle its visibility.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand. But I'm not trying to create an antivirus. I want to prevent the unauthorized users from running some programs (and to prevent these programs from being started inadvertently) - I assume that no _counter application_ is previously running.
It seems I have to run the application under the user account, but how do I run the application with admin privileges when the user is not an admin? The application must be able to run either automatically or when the user requests it.

Comment: The system already has everything you're trying to re-implement. See [Access Control Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-model).